# Is guice FactoryModuleBuilder().implements() optional?

Tags: java, guice

```
class TestClass {
    @Inject
    public TestClass(String arg1, @Assisted String arg2) {
        System.out.printf("TestClass(%s, %s)\n", arg1, arg2);
    }
}


interface TestFactory {
    TestClass makeTestClass(String extraArg);
}

class Main {
    @Inject
    public TestFactory factory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector i = Guice.createInjector(
            new AbstractModule() { @Override protected void configure() {
                bind(String.class).toInstance("any string");
                install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(TestFactory.class));
            }}
        );

        Main m = i.getInstance(Main.class);

    m.factory.makeTestClass("assisted");
    }
}
```

This code works correctly and print "TestClass(any string, assisted)"

But by doc i must call something like

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
    .implement(TestClassInterface.class, TestClass.class)
    .build(TestFactory.class));
```

When and why I really must use implement()? Only when do named bindings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.implement()` when the return type of your factory method is not the same type you want Guice to instantiate.  Usually this happens if your factory method returns an interface type.  You use `.implement()` to tell Guice the concrete class type it should be creating.

Comment: ah, clear, it just additional optional bind().to() and not mandatory